# C - How to extract integers from a mixed char array (arduino)

Tags: strtok, arduino-c++

I am trying to extract the time from a char array, and store it into an integer (for example (092703). The char array looks like this:

"2018-09-20T09:27:03>2023-09-20T13:03:33"

I have been reading up on strtok and it seems to be what I need to use to at least break up the char array so I can deal with each individual time portion ( for example 09:27:03). I have a child strtok function there to break down each datetime period into just the time:

```
char * sub_pch;
    sub_pch = strtok (pch,"T");
    while (sub_pch != NULL)
    {
      printf ("Splitting sub string:\n");
      printf ("%s\n",sub_pch);
      sub_pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
```

However the output isnt what I expetected. Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, and I don't need to use strtok? Ive tried different solutions provided on this site but none seem to output what I need. Any advice would be greately appreciated! :) My test code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello, ESP32-S2!");



  char str[] ="2018-09-20T09:27:03>2023-09-20T13:03:33";
  char * pch;
  
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,">");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    char * sub_pch;
    sub_pch = strtok (pch,"T");
    while (sub_pch != NULL)
    {
      printf ("Splitting sub string:\n");
      printf ("%s\n",sub_pch);
      sub_pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
      
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(10); // this speeds up the simulation
}
```

**and the output is: **

Splitting string "2018-09-20T09:27:03>2023-09-20T13:03:33" into tokens:
2018-09-20T09:27:03
Splitting sub string:
2023-09-20
Splitting sub string:
13:03:33
2023-09-20

**My expected output for this code is **

2018-09-20T09:27:03
Splitting sub string:
2023-09-20
09:27:03
Splitting sub string:
2023-09-20
13:03:33

**My ideal output would be an int array with **

09:27:03,
13:03:33

Thanks for any help you can offer me.

Comment: arduino is C++, not C,

Comment: Suggest you use "T>" as the delimiter for a few calls to `strtok()`, then capture the 2nd and 4th pointers it returns... That will give you the two time fields. `strtok()` doesn't allow you to use in a "nested" fashion... PS: hh:mm:ss is not an integer...

Comment: @Piglet Ah apologies thanks for updating.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thanks ill have a look at that. Aware that it still has the : char, was planning to use something like strtol to extract digits but not quite there yet..

Comment: Yes, `strtol()` for the conversion. Be careful about "00:02:45"... Leading zeros need some consideration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on new information, the following may be what you are looking for.

The always well formed string has two fields of "...Thh:mm:ss".

The trick is to find the *herald* 'T', then convert the three pairs of digits to an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int hmsTOint( char *p ) {
    int val = 0;
    val = strtol( p+1, &p, 10 );
    val = strtol( p+1, &p, 10 ) + val * 100;
    val = strtol( p+1, &p, 10 ) + val * 100;
    return val;
}

int main( void ) {
    char *str = "2018-09-20T09:27:03>2023-09-20T13:03:33", *p = str;
    int arr[2] = { 0 };

    for( int i = 0; i < 2 && (p = strchr( p+1, 'T' ) ) != NULL; i++ )
        arr[i] = hmsTOint( p );

    printf( "%d, %d\n", arr[0], arr[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

```
92703, 130333
```

Note: although these integers "look like" the time they represent, another version would replace the value `100` in the function with `60`. The numbers may look different, but will represent the time as "seconds since midnight".

---

**EDIT:**
If the size of the binary allows using a larger library function (that might be useful elsewhere in the program) there's also the `sscanf()` option.

```
int hmsTOint( char *p ) {
    int h, m, s;
    if( sscanf( p+1, "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s ) == 3 )
        return (h * 100 + m) * 100 + s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! I'll try this later. The format is always the same, and I actually need it 100 format to run some calcualtions so thats perfect. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If your input always matches the exact pattern that you provided you could parse the time like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * append(const char *s, char * c) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  char buf[len+2];
  strcpy(buf, s);
  buf[len] = *c;
  buf[len+1] = 0;
  return strdup(buf);
}

int main() {

  char * input = "2018-09-20T09:27:03>2023-09-20T13:03:33";
  
  int numMin     = 0x30; // 0
  int numMax     = 0x39; // 9
  int timeToken  = 0x54; // T
  int partToken  = 0x3a; // :

  char * out = "";
  char current;
  
  int begin = 0;
  
  size_t len = strlen(input);
  for (size_t i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    current = input[i];
    
    if (current == timeToken) {
      begin = 1;
      continue; 
    }

    if (begin) {
      if ((current >= numMin && current <= numMax) || current == partToken) { 
            out  = append(out, &current);
      }
      else {
        out = append(out, ",");
        out = append(out, " ");
        begin = 0;
      }
    }
    
  }

  printf("intput: %s\noutput: %s\n", input, out);
  return 0;
}
```

The printed result would look like that:

```
intput: 2018-09-20T09:27:03>2023-09-20T13:03:33
output: 09:27:03, 13:03:33
```

Since dates can take a large number of different formats I'd recommend using regex patterns, or normalizing your input by removing characters like `<` and trying to use `strftime`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Max. That looks great - the char array should always be in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS. I would like the final output to be an integer array, for example 09:27:03 should be 92703 (no need for leadingzeros). Ive tried strtol but this exits at the first ":". Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You could implement a linked list or split the output by ', ' and parse the numbers to an integer. You would first need to count the number of valid characters (excluding leading zeros) and then create an array with the required size. You can also just convert the characters to int by doing the following: `int x = current - '0';`