# How do I divide a date into a day, a month and a year in C?

Tags: c

I am new to C and I would like to ask for help to write a function that splits a date that is stored in a string array into a day, a month and a year, each stored in separate integer variables. I appreciate any help.

I defined the following array and variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char Date[] = "02/02/2023";

    int Day, Month, Year;

    }
```

I expect my variables to contain the following values at the end:

```
Day = 02

Month = 02

Year = 2023
```

I know of this function but it only works when the date is entered by the user in the command prompt:

```
scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &Day, &Month, &Year);
```

I want my function to work the same but on a date that is stored in an array.

Comment: Use the `sscanf` function: `sscanf(Date, "%d/%d/%d", &Day, &Month, &Year);`

Comment: You can also separate the components with `strtok()` using a delimiter of `"/"` (or `"/-"` to make it more general) and then use `strtol()` to convert to integer values. You can also do it by hand with a single pointer walking down the date-string manually converting from string to integer value and moving to the next each time a delimiter is encountered and ending when the nul-terminating character is reached. Good learning exercise to do it all three ways. (and then alternate `strcspn()` and `strspn()` as a 4th)

Comment: what do you mean by *" but on a date that is stored in an array"?*

Comment: @0___________ - I think he was missing the fact that `sscanf()` would separate the the components from an existing array instead of `scanf()` that is limited to separating what they read from `stdin`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If the string is "well formed" (consistent), one can go straight to `strtol()` and skip the `strtok()` that may be problematic in the case of a string literal. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303655/17592432 (for "hh:mm:ss", but strong correspondence. Here OP wants 3 separate values, not a conglomeration as a single value, but...) `:-)`

Comment: Yes, the comment about operation on string-literals was implied. Though it would have been better to make that explicit. Thus my preference to just walk the string or alternate `strcspn()` and `strspn()` if not using `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sscanf` instead of `scanf`:

```c
if(sscanf(Date, "%d/%d/%d", &Day, &Month, &Year) == 3) {
    // success
}
```

Or, if you have a POSIX library, the power of [`strptime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) to parse the input may be useful:

```c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE // Define this before including anything
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
/*
char *strptime(const char *restrict s, const char *restrict format,
               struct tm *restrict tm);
*/

int main() {
    char Date[] = "02/02/2023 Foo";

    struct tm tp;
    char *res = strptime(Date, "%d/%m/%Y", &tp);

    if (res == NULL) {
        // the time point could not be parsed
        printf("could not parse [%s]\n", Date);
    } else {
        // the time point was parsed ok
        printf("%d-%02d-%02d\n", tp.tm_year + 1900, tp.tm_mon + 1, tp.tm_mday);

        if (*res != '\0') {
            // but there was some more text after the parsed time point:
            printf("rest of string [%s]\n", res);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2023-02-02
rest of string [ Foo]
```

[Demo with validation and normalization](https://godbolt.org/z/33q9fPhjo)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I was working on it for many hours with no results. Now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To convert any string containing numbers into integers, you can use the `strtol` family of functions. In the simplest form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char date[] = "02/02/2023";
  int day, month, year;
  char* endptr;
  char* next;

  next = date;
  day   = strtoul(next, &endptr, 10);
  next = endptr+1;
  month = strtoul(next, &endptr, 10);
  next = endptr+1;
  year  = strtoul(next, &endptr, 10);

  printf("%d %d %d\n", day, month, year);
}
```

Or use somewhat more advanced but generic form with a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char date[] = "02/02/2023";
  int day, month, year;
  int* const items[3] = { &day, &month, &year };
  char* endptr;
  char* next=date;
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<3 && *next!='\0'; i++)
  {
    *items[i] = strtoul(next, &endptr, 10);
    if(endptr == next)
    {
      /* handle errors here */
      return 0;
    }
    next = endptr+1; // could also loop here til finding next digit
  } 
  
  printf("%d %d %d\n", day, month, year);
}
```